# Using SCP or SFTP with my SSH config file?

Tags: command-line, terminal, scp, sftp

I'd like to connect and upload a MySQL dump file via terminal using SFTP or SCP to my remote server using my SSH config file. According to the documentation I've found, I should be able to do this:

```
sftp -F db.sql.gz webost@staging2.example.com /tmp
```

I have also tried the alias in my config:

```
sftp -F db.sql.gz myalias /tmp
```

When I do the two above, I simply get a print-out of possible commands, `-F` being one of them.

I can already connect via SSH using the shortcut in my local config just fine so I know that works:

```
ssh myalias
```

---

**Note**: I am connecting using a private/public key pair so I never need to enter a password. The key pair does have a passphrase associated with it but OS X Keychain remembered that the first time I connected.

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

1. From the help text: "`... [-F ssh_config] ...`"

   According to the above, `-F` expects one argument: path to an OpenSSH configuration file, `~/.ssh/config` or similar. But you are giving it a gzipped SQL dump instead.

   Since plain `ssh myalias` is already working, you don't even need the `-F` option here. Just `sftp myalias` would connect to the server.
2. However, the OpenSSH `sftp` client does not support uploading files like you are trying to; it can only download files (using the syntax `host:path`) or work in interactive mode. For uploading, you need to use either the interactive mode...

   ```
   $ sftp myalias
   sftp> cd /tmp
   sftp> put db.sql.gz
   ```

   ...or the `scp` tool:

   ```
   scp db.sql.gz myalias:/tmp
   ```

   or

   ```
   scp db.sql.gz webost@staging2.example.com:/tmp
   ```

(sftp does have a batch mode in which it can read commands from a file, using `-b`, but it is simpler to use `scp` for single uploads.)

There are other SFTP clients as well – *lftp* is good for interactive use, while *curl* can be easier to automate. For backups and such, you could also use *rsync* (which runs its own protocol but still inside SSH).

Comment: wow this is perfect, worked great! I am just getting familiar with terminal so this will really come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Problem caused by ForwardAgent config as below,

```
Host dockervm
   HostName x.x.x.x
   User root
   Preferredauthentications publickey
   ForwardAgent yes
```

My case, it was due to the 'ForwardAgent' on the ssh config causing the scp to hang. Once commenting it out, worked for me.

Also, you could have an copy of the file with the ForwardAgent line commented and use scp -F to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a quick experiment and it worked, so I thought I’d share my little discovery.[Read more...](https://medium.com/code-kings/linux-ubuntu-how-to-use-ssh-config-to-simplify-scp-commands-48f464acfa82)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).